# Why is event.userInfo null?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I have the following code:

**Injected.js**

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu, false);
function handleContextMenu(event) 
{
    var target = event.target;
    while(target != null && target.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE 
    && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "a") 
    {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

        var userInfo = {
        "name": event.target.nodeName,
        "url": target.href,
    }
    safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, userInfo);
}
```

**Global.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <script>
        safari.application.addEventListener("command",foo,false);
        function foo(event)
        {
            if(event.command === "doStuff")
            {
                if(!event.userInfo)
                {
                    alert("No userinfo");
                }

                if (event.userInfo.url) 
                {
                                var link = event.userInfo.url;

                    safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = link;
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

The alert is always triggered - my `userInfo` object seems to always be `null`. Why is this?

EDIT: Since `userInfo` is null, the second `if` block is never entered.

EDIT: I also have the following code in my **global.html** file too, but `userInfo` is null here too:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("contextmenu",handleContextMenu,false);

var lastUrl;

function handleContextMenu(event)
{
    if(!event.userInfo)
    {
        lastUrl = "foot";
    }
    else
    {
        //lastUrl = event.userInfo.url;
        lastUrl = "hand";
    }
}
```

`lastUrl` is always "foot"...

Comment: Am I correct assuming that you call `event.contextMenu.appendContextMenuItem` from somewhere in your global page code?

Comment: No - I don't call appendContextMenuItem anywhere.

Comment: Then how is the `command` event handler invoked?

Comment: By clicking on a "context menu item". When you right click on a link or something, the context menu pops up. Then you click the context menu item for the extension.

Comment: Oh, the ones defined in the Extension Builder GUI? Back in my days we didn't have that, we had to call `appendContextMenuItem` to add context menu items.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this looks good. We're probably both overlooking something simple.

Comment: Yeah - I add the menu item through the guy. But the problem is, I can't get to transfer "userInfo" from my injected script to my global.html file. userInfo is always null.